# Sessions and HTTP Authentication

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I have a website where users use http authentication to login and what I would like to do is start a session with their username to pass across the pages to pull files based on that username later.

I understand and have another site where I do this against a sql database (showing abit of code just for example):

```
//session variables here, etc etc
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db) or die('Failed to select database<br>'.mysql_error());
   $sql = "SELECT password, fullname, active FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
   if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      if ($crypt_pass == $data['password'] && $data['active'] != 0)
      {
         $found = true;
         $fullname = $data['fullname'];
      }
   }
   mysql_close($db);
   if($found == false)
   {
      header('Location: '.$error_page);
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
      if (session_id() == "")
      {
         session_start();
      }
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;
      $_SESSION['expires_by'] = time() + $session_timeout;
      $_SESSION['expires_timeout'] = $session_timeout;
      $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']) ? true : false;
      if ($rememberme)
      {
         setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time() + 3600*24*30);
         setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time() + 3600*24*30);
      }

and then using this on subsequent pages to get that info:

    <?php
    if (session_id() == "")
    {
       session_start();
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
```

I've been looking into $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] but am unsure if that's the right direction of what I'm missing. There is a text file that has their usernames and passwords on it that I can pull from just not sure how to set it or find it compared to how I would the sql database unless I'm over-thinking it.

I just basically need to pass on a session username based on their http authentication login so I can carry it over to a couple of other pages.

Comment: your using http  basic authentication ? (http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I can work off of that, hadn't found that yet. I appreciate it Dagon.

Comment: added a bit of an answer for what it is worth ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
$_SESSION['user']=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
}
```

where ever needed:

```
echo $_SESSION['user']
```

and don't forget to add `session_start();` on the pages you use sessions (before any output)

Comment: Thank you Dagon, gives me something to work with. So I could essentially put <? session_start();
      } if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
$_SESSION['user']=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
} ?> on the page they login/enter from and that should carry over to the other pages, is that correct?

Comment: `isset` not `!isset` , sorry about that

Comment: all good I got it, and thank you again Dagon for the help, at least I had the php_auth_user right I just thought there was more to it. Working through it all now, many thanks.